Holes under a plastic sheeting
Recently I've done some work around the house, basically reshaping the landscape and found these small holes in the ground under a 6 mil black plastic sheet. I put the sheet years ago just to cover the ground and get rid of weeds and added rocks on top of it. Also the same small holes I saw them in the crawlspace. The crawlspace is neat and clean with NO rodents at all, dry, no signs of them but these holes under a plastic sheet..........I don't know what are those. Has something like this happened to someone before?
What are these holes?



Edit: hole size is about 1 to 1.5 inch not more

From photos it is difficult to have an estimate of the size. Could you add such information?

@Giacomo, I'll say the hole size is about 1 to 1.5 inch not more

I'm pretty sure - your statements about rodents  notwithstanding - they are some kind of small digging animal (muscilid like a weasel or stoat ? )

It's hard to tell what could be living in those holes but the only thing that could have caused this are rodents like moles, groundhog, mice, rats, weezels etc. this isn't something to be worried about as your home sits on their home. If they're being respectable then there's no real need to worry

I've seen squirrels or mice do something similar when looking for water.

squirrels doesn't live/dig underneath a plastic sheeting that's covered with rocks.
